# SAS: Macros: Substring and Replacement

Tags: macros, sas, substr

I have two simple macros:

```
%macro One(mvStr);
      /*some code here to replace varOne -> stringOne*/     

%mend One;

%macro Two;
    %local mvStr;
    %let mvStr = "String varOne StringvarOneString";
    %One(&mvStr);
%mend Two;
```

So, How to replace all substrings `varOne` with `stringOne`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want...

```
%macro One(mvStr);
  /*some code here to replace varOne -> stringOne*/     
  %Sysfunc(tranwrd(&mvStr, varOne, StringOne));
%mend One;

%macro Two;
    %local mvStr;
    %let mvStr = "String varOne StringvarOneString";
    %let mvStr = %One(&mvStr);

    %put &mvStr; 
%mend Two;

%two;
```

Comment: The line beginning with %sysfunc should not have a semicolon at the end because it will get included in the returned value.  If you want to see why this matters try putting additional markers around your call to %one like this: `%let mvStr = #%One(&mvStr)#;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Did not know if you have to have two macros, but would the following suffice?


%macro one(mvStr, From, To);
  %local mvStr From To;
  %let &mvStr. = "String &From. String&From.String";
  %put  %Qsysfunc(prxchange(s/&From./&To./,-1,&mvStr.));
  %*put &mvStr.; 
%mend;

options mprint;
%one(mvStr,varOne,StringOne)
```